# Auto-suggest input box from RESTful API using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an input box that I would like to fill with suggestions incrementally as the user inputs characters -- you know, google style.

My challenge is that the suggestions could number thousands and it seems inappropriate to load that many into the webpage. Fortunately I have build a RESTful API that can be queried for the list, or parts of the list. So I was thinking that maybe I could leverage that API and tie it into AngularJS somehow.

How do I tell AngularJS to autocomplete (i.e. suggest) an input box from a list generated by the return value of the RESTful API based on what the user types in that input box?

Comment: Did you took a look at ngAutocomplete? http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742393/search-a-user-in-a-list-of-usernames-in-angularjs/25745715#comment40285369_25745715) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Typeahead from Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (scroll to bottom of page)

Comment: Almost too easy. Almost.